# Grabbing parts of a line until a white space

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a line of text that looks something like:

```
2018-05-22 00:00:00 STATUS ERROR_CODE /home/etm124/script.py ANOTHER_MSG
```

What I want to do is grab the script name. I cannot split on white space because the `STATUS` could be more than one word, however the script value is always in location [411] of `line`. I currently am trying to do something like:

```
with open(my_log, 'r') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        if line[45] == '7':    #ERROR_CODE
            print line[411: {white_space?}]
```

Comment: `line[411:].partition(" ")[0]` should do the trick

Comment: You could extract a string from 411 to the end of the line and THEN split on your white spaces.

Comment: great answer @Jean-FrançoisFabre . I did the following `line[411: 411 + line[411:].find(" ")]` which isnt very neat !

Comment: yeah! it's better to avoid all that slicing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use `str.find` with an offset:

```
offset = 411
line[offset:line.find(" ",offset)]
```

It's fast (one slice only) but the problem is: if there's no space, you'd get `-1` as a result and you lose 1 char.

The alternative is slicing *then* splitting/partitionning (even if there's no space afterwards it works):

```
line[411:].split()[0]
```

Some more intricate code to handle the "missing space" and only perform 1 slice & 1 find would be:

```
offset = 411
spacepos = line.find(" ",offset)
line[offset:spacepos if spacepos != -1 else None])
```

so if `find` returns -1, slice to the end of the string.